# Python to_csv changes empty rows to empty strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a file where I want to update certain values in Python and then save again to be used in another program. The extention is .OPL, but it can be read using pandas.read_csv().

The file has multiple empty rows and when I import it, it shows these empty rows as nan:

*File*

[image]

*Import in Python*

[image]

Now when I save the updated dataframe, I use pandas.to_csv() that is able to save it to .OPL right away. The issue however is that all empty rows are now filled with empty strings:

[image]

This is an issue since the other program is not able to read this.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Will `df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, na_rep=" ")` help?

Comment: Is there only one column in the file?

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome that is the default value of `na_rep`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single field with so-called missing values (NaN) are a problem when writing csv (as you have discovered). What you would like to do is use the option `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` but then you run into the error `Error: single empty field record must be quoted.` Probably it would be nice if the default quoting would work too (`csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`), but it doesn't - not when there is only one field.

However, just write the rows without using `to_csv`. Especially with a single column dataframe this is very easy to handle.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'MyColumn': ["x", np.nan, "y", np.nan, "z"]})

# just write the column to a new csv file without using to_csv
with open("test.csv", "w") as f:
    for row in df["MyColumn"]:
        f.write("\n" if pd.isna(row) else row + "\n")
```